# Rhythmbox and soundcloud

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhythmbox

Recently I installed Rhythmbox application on my laptop, which uses Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, and I faced a problem with soundcloud plugin, which I had installed in program. How can I add my music to Rhythmbox with this plugin? There is no button like "Add" or "Login/Register" on soundcloud. I don't include a fact that I'm very inattentive, so don't be mad much.

Answer (score -2):

Try this. Go to settings and re-enable plugin.
(i had the same problem (ubuntu 21.04). i clicked it several times and it somehow helped :-)

Comment: Not work's breda.